# Android Room list of keyword search

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to search a list of keyword in Room. Currently i can search a single keyword like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM customer where content LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%'  and status = 'published'")
LiveData<List<Customer>> getSearchResult(String keyword);
```

But how can i search a list of keyword in a easy way.

Is there easy way like `IN` with Collection arguments like:

```
@Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE region IN (:regions)")
public List<NameTuple> loadUsersFromRegions(List<String> regions);
```

I know i can build query for multiple keyword manually but i want to pass a Collection as a argument.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using full-text search. There are somewhat hacky ways of doing that now (see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/FINAL/TimeMachine/RoomFTS), and Room 2.1.0 [has built-in FTS support](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Fts4?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks i will check this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code for `FTS` search. Joined keyword with `OR`

```
    String keywordAll = TextUtils.join("* OR *", keywordList);
    keywordAll = "*" + keywordAll + "*";
```

For query used `MATCH` for search

```
WHERE Posts MATCH :keyword
```

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL this is an easy thing to do by using FTS3 or FTS4 it's a Full Text Search these two are the newest features in SQL but I'm struggling on how to configure this into my android projects. I under stand a bit about room but not enough to give a an accurate answer I'm still researching this myself but have not found an answer. Please let me know if you find a way to configure it. I've been on this issue for weeks now but I know from knowing more about SQL that it is the FTS functions that are needed.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the comment before posting the answer.